# How to use Cookies in Swagger editor

Tags: cookies, swagger-editor

I would like to document and test an API, which uses Cookie-based authetication in http://editor.swagger.io/. To give a simple example: How to write in the following YAML, that /login action creates a Cookie and the Cookie has to be passed to /showMySecretStuff?

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  title: Test API
  version: '1'
host: my.test.com
schemes:
  - https
basePath: /
consumes:
  - multipart/form-data
produces:
  - application/json
paths:
  /login:
    post:
      parameters:
        - name: username
          in: formData
          required: true
          type: string
        - name: password
          in: formData
          required: true
          type: string
          default: secret
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK
  /showMySecretStuff:
    get:
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cookie authentication is supported in OpenAPI 3.0 but not in OpenAPI/Swagger 2.0.

In OpenAPI 3.0, cookie authentication is defined as an API key that is sent `in: cookie`:

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.1
...

components:
  securitySchemes:
    cookieAuth:
      type: apiKey
      in: cookie
      name: COOKIE-NAME  # replace with your cookie name

paths:
  /showMySecretStuff:
    get:
      security:
        - cookieAuth: []
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
```

The login operation is not linked to `securitySchemes` in any way, but you may want to define the response header `Set-Cookie` for documentation purposes:

```yaml
paths:
  /login:
    post:
      requestBody:
        ...
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
          headers:
            Set-Cookie:
              description: >
                Contains the session cookie named `COOKIE-NAME`.
                Pass this cookie back in subsequent requests.
              schema: 
                type: string
```

That said, Swagger Editor and Swagger UI currently don't support cookie authentication. Check out the [OAS 3.0 Support Backlog](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/3641) and [this issue](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-js/issues/1163) for updates.

Cookie auth is supported in [SwaggerHub](https://app.swaggerhub.com) though. *(Disclosure: SwaggerHub is a product of the company I work for.)*